# How to get timezone indicator with colon using the Pandas strftime method

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format

For a pandas timestamp:

```
pd.Timestamp.today(tz = 'Europe/London')
```

How can I format the time in the following way (with the colon present in the timezone component)?:

```
'2023-12-04 16:08:02+00:00'
```

Pandas claims to contain all native Python strftime directives:
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.strftime.html

And Python claims to support the `'%:z'` directive, which is what I need:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Thus, the following code:

```
pd.Timestamp.today(tz = 'Europe/London').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X%:z')
```

should give my desired answer, but instead raises `ValueError: Invalid format string`, as it does not recognise `'%:z'`.

Comment: You mean `pd.Timestamp.today(tz = 'Europe/London').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %X:%z')`?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM No, I do not mean that. the '%:z' directive is a Python-native srftime directive that adds the colon between the hour and minute timezone difference indicator. Your code returns: '2023-12-04 16:08:02:+00:00'

Comment: The following, whilst returning the correct answer, is clunky:
a = pd.Timsetamp.today();
desired_format = a.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') + a.strftime('%z')[:3] + ':' + a.strftime('%z')[3:]

Comment: I mean `%z` not(`%:z`)

Comment: Ah, I see. The problem with '%z' is that it formats without the colon by default (+0000, for example). Python say that '%:z' is the directive to produce (+00:00), but it's not working with Pandas, even though it's stated that it should in the docs.,

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried making the [`isoformat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.isoformat.html) ?

```
ts = pd.Timestamp.today(tz="Europe/London")

out = ts.isoformat(timespec="seconds", sep=" ") # 2023-12-04 17:27:28+00:00
```